# Making a contract with new keyword address is always 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tags: solidity, struct, constructor

I'm making a contract that makes other contracts.  Once the contract is made using `address tokenAddress = new MyToken('Name');` I want to save the address of the contract, `tokenAddress`, in `MyStruct`.  The problem is that `myMapping[uuid].tokenAddress` is always `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.  I'm guessing this is the default.

My question is, how do I get the address of where a contract is deployed?

```
struct MyStruct {
    string someData;
    address tokenAddress;
}

mapping (uint256 => MyStruct) myMapping;

function makeContract(uint256 uuid) view public {
    address tokenAddress = new MyToken('Name');
    myMapping[uuid].tokenAddress = tokenAddress;
}
```

**EDIT**:

I changed the signature of `makeContract`

```
function makeContract(uint256 uuid) view public returns (address, uint256) {
    address tokenAddress = new MyToken('Name');
    myMapping[uuid].tokenAddress = tokenAddress;
    return (tokenAddress, uuid);
}
```

and now it returns an address.  So now I'm trying to figure out why `myMapping[uuid].tokenAddress` isn't working.

One possible thing is that early in the contract I have to initialize some variables:

```
function setData(uint256 uuid, string someData) public {
    var struct_ = myMapping[uuid];
    struct_.someData= someData;
}
```

then later on I call `makeContract`.  Is it possible the modifying the struct is causing the problem?

Comment: which version of solidity are you using, can you share the token contract?

Comment: @Alexis Are you sure your call to `makeContract` succeeded? Your code should work. Contract creation never returns `0x0` as address.

Comment: Why do you return one of the input parameters? It apparently does not make sense.

Comment: Returning an input variable just for testing/sanity.. Will remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t you face errors from compiler?

Any ‘never created’ and ‘not existent’ mapping element returns zero if you try to read from it.

Consider that this is not a view function, it cannot be because you write in storage.

```
    myMapping[uuid].tokenAddress = tokenAddress;
```

This cannot be executed by a view function!

You can  paste your code in remix and follow compiler warning and errors. It can help.

I add that the use of ‘new’ you are doing is correct: just be sure to have gas for it.

Comment: The code is a little bit more complicated so was trying to make it easy with a smaller example.  Good pickup.  I fixed the code.

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

Comment: I suggest you try to fix the code from a syntactic point of view in order to reflect your aim and use. After it you can resubmit it if it does not work. The use of new you do is correct, just be sure to have enough gas for it.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see.  I think the `view` was the issue.  Am trying it now.

Comment: What is the cose?

Comment: Yes, keep us posted! “Cose” was “code”. Sorry 

Comment: It works!  The problem was the `view` function modifier!

Comment: Happy to hear that. Very strange your IDE did not warning you. I’ll trim the answer accordingly then, because now it is misleading.

Comment: The Sublime text editor/Truffle/solc mix leaves much to be desired.  I tried remix in the browser linked to the local file system via http:localhost but it was hard to use..  Maybe I should go back to it?  What do you like?

Comment: I suggest hardly to use remix. You should have remix to develop your code and, optionally, you can use truffle+solc to have a test workbench if you encounter some limitation. Remix is grown up very much in the last year. Moreover assist you in avoiding avoidable errors like this and to focus on the code. I work using all the colors (remix, ganache, truffle, Geth, etc etc), but by far my preferite IDE is remix. I must be honest and say that I never tested Vcode for Solidity, even if I use it for JavaScript. Someone claim it is cool. At the moment I have some urgent work to do... next!

Comment: Will give Remix another shake.  Thanks for the help and advice!